# matlab problem in plotting a function

Tags: matlab, plot

I have 2 functions:

```
f (aa) = 9 sinaa/aa + cosaa  for 0 <= aa <= 6pi.      --- >equation 1.

and f(aa) = cosku
```

I need to plot the allowed values of aa which will satisfy the equation 1.
How do i do this i matlab?

Comment: i dont know how to do it matlab...

Comment: I guess this is homework and is then related to a course you had about Matlab ... you should at least have a basic idea of what to do... This problem did showed up by itself when you woke up ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is homework, and your question is not really clear about `k u` but here is a short answer.

You can plot `f(a)` and `cos(k u)` on the same plot, and then graphically find the solutions of the equation.

Here is a very basic example of code:

```
a=0:0.01:6*pi;
f = 9*sin(a)./a+cos(a);
plot(a,f)
hold on
u = 0:0.01:6*pi;
f2 = cos(u);
plot(u,f2)
```

Comment: a=0:0.01:6*pi;  can you please elaborate this? what does this line mean?

Comment: Run it and test it ... Yes it defines a vector containing the adequate number of elements to allow a span from 0 to 6pi by steps of 0.01.

Comment: Don't forget to put `hold off` at the end.

Comment: I m getting the graph but how do i indicate the values of a which will satisfy the equation 1??

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know basic MATLAB syntax, you need to start at the beginning. Mathworks has published a beginner's guide for MATLAB, the [Getting Started Guide](http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/getstart.pdf). Read this, and if you have any further questions, come back to SO. You can also use the `help` or `doc` functions in MATLAB to gain more understanding about what a built-in function does. For example, `doc sin` will bring up the documentation page for the `sin` function.

Answer (score 0):

Also look at the [EZPLOT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ezplot.html) function. In addition you will also need [YLIM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/xlim.html) to show the whole curve.

To get intersections of two curves you can use [Fast and Robust Curve Intersections](http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11837-fast-and-robust-curve-intersections) from FileExchange. For this function you can use data you've got using [Cedric's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698792/matlab-problem-in-plotting-a-function/3698836#3698836).